# android code that saves current time in a audio recording?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

Hi i'm working on a android app that records audio I Need the application to have the functionality where someone hit a button and it seems the current time in the recording for example say I'm in class and I'm recording the lecture when I go back to listen to the lecture later see there's a spot I need to come back and listen to again I need to be able to click a button and it seems the current time in the recording so will say 2 minutes and 35 seconds this is a saved in a textview this way when I come back later I can go to where I need to go and not have to listen to the whole recording again the only problem is I do not know how to do this in code

Here's my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PlayingTimeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/MediaPlayerSeek"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/StartTimeText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/StartTimeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/PlayerButtonsLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="00:00:00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EndTimeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/PlayerButtonsLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/PlayerButtonsLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/BackToStartButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/backtostart_icon"
        />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/PlayerBackButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/playerback_icon"
        />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/MediaPlayerButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/FastForwardButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/fastforward_icon"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Go Back Time" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gobacktime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/MediaPlayerSeek"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/PlayingTimeText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/EndTimeText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Java code:

```
package com.d4a.voicerecorder;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.audiofx.Equalizer;
import android.media.audiofx.Visualizer;
import android.media.audiofx.Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.dva.RecodeTime.R;

public class MeidaPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG ="VoiceRecorder_MeidaPlayerActivity";
int progres;

//int val ;
    //private AudioManager m_AudioManager;
    //private int m_nRecordVolume;
    //private int m_nOtherVolume;
    private MediaPlayer m_MediaPlayer = null;
    private SeekBar m_SeekBar;
    private TextView m_NowTimeText , startTime;
    private ImageButton m_MediaPlayerButton;

    private Handler m_Handler;
    private Timer m_TimeCountTimer = null;
    private Timer m_ButtonClickHandleTimer = null;
    private boolean m_Playing = false;

    private VisualizerView m_VisualizerView;
    private Equalizer m_Equalizer;
    private Visualizer m_Visualizer;

    Button button;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayerview);

        startTime =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.StartTimeText);
         //val = getVal("k");
            button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


        //Tools.setRecoedVolume(this);

        /*
        m_AudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        m_nOtherVolume = m_AudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        if(sp.getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.VolumeAutoSetKey), false) == true){
            m_nRecordVolume = sp.getInt(getResources().getString(R.string.RecordVolumeKey), m_AudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        }else{
            m_nRecordVolume = m_nOtherVolume;
        }
        */

//      DataBaseHelper base= new DataBaseHelper(MeidaPlayerActivity.this);
//      base.insertImageUrl("dinesh");




            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    DataBaseHelper baseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(MeidaPlayerActivity.this);
                    baseHelper.insertImageUrl(String.valueOf(progres));
                }
            });




        m_MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        m_Handler = new Handler();
        m_TimeCountTimer = new Timer(true);
    //  dataBase.insertImageUrl("jhg");
        if(SDCardCtrl.checkSDCard(this) == true){
            m_MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(new File(getIntent().getStringExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.IntentAudioFilePathKey)))));
            try {
                m_MediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            //  e.printStackTrace();
            }
            m_MediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            m_MediaPlayer.start();
            m_NowTimeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlayingTimeText);

            m_SeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.MediaPlayerSeek);
            m_SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                    m_MediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                    m_NowTimeText.setText(Tools.ConversionTime(progress));
                    startTime.setText(Tools.ConversionTime(progress));
                    progres = progress;


                    //val
                    //===============================================
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    m_Playing = m_MediaPlayer.isPlaying();
                    if(m_Playing == true){
                        m_MediaPlayer.pause();
                        //m_MediaPlayerButton.setText(R.string.AudioPlayerStartButtonText);
                        m_MediaPlayerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audioplay_icon);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    if(m_Playing == true){
                        m_MediaPlayer.start();
                        m_Playing = false;
                        m_MediaPlayerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audiopause_icon);
                        //m_MediaPlayerButton.setText(R.string.AudioPlayerPauseButtonText);
                    }
                }
            });
            m_SeekBar.setMax(m_MediaPlayer.getDuration());

            TextView EndTimeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EndTimeText);
            EndTimeText.setText(Tools.ConversionTime(m_MediaPlayer.getDuration()));
        }

        ImageButton BackToStartButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.BackToStartButton);
        BackToStartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                m_MediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                m_SeekBar.setProgress(0);
                m_NowTimeText.setText(Tools.ConversionTime(0));
            }
        });

        ImageButton PlayerBackButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.PlayerBackButton);
        //ãƒœã‚¿ãƒ³ã�®æŠ¼ã�—ã�Ÿæ™‚ã�¨ãƒœã‚¿ãƒ³ã‚’é›¢ã�—ã�Ÿæ™‚ã�®Handleã‚’å�–å¾—ã�™ã‚‹ã�Ÿã‚�TouchListenerã�«ã�™ã‚‹
        PlayerBackButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    if(m_MediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true){
                        m_MediaPlayer.pause();
                        m_Playing = true;
                    }
                    setControlPlayerTimer(-(m_MediaPlayer.getDuration() / Config.PLAYER_FORWARD_BACK_TIMESPAN));
                    return true;
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    if(m_Playing == true){
                        m_MediaPlayer.start();
                        m_Playing = false;
                    }
                    m_ButtonClickHandleTimer = ReleaseTimer(m_ButtonClickHandleTimer);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });









//playButton-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        m_MediaPlayerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.MediaPlayerButton);
        m_MediaPlayerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(m_MediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true){
                    m_MediaPlayer.pause();
                    m_MediaPlayerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audioplay_icon);
                    //SharedPreferences preferences = SharedPreferences.

//                  String ss = String.valueOf(progres);
//                  saveVal(ss);
    //              m_NowTimeText.setText(Tools.ConversionTime(progres));
            //String ss = String.valueOf(progres);

                    ;

                }else{
                    m_MediaPlayer.start();
                    m_MediaPlayerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audiopause_icon);
//                  int timeGet = getVal("k");
//                  Log.d(TAG, "time get : "+timeGet);
//                  System.out.println("bbbbb "+timeGet);
//                  m_NowTimeText.setText(Tools.ConversionTime(progres));
                }
            }


        });
        m_MediaPlayerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audiopause_icon);
        //m_MediaPlayerButton.setText(R.string.AudioPlayerPauseButtonText);

        ImageButton FastForwardButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.FastForwardButton);
        //ãƒœã‚¿ãƒ³ã�®æŠ¼ã�—ã�Ÿæ™‚ã�¨ãƒœã‚¿ãƒ³ã‚’é›¢ã�—ã�Ÿæ™‚ã�®Handleã‚’å�–å¾—ã�™ã‚‹ã�Ÿã‚�TouchListenerã�«ã�™ã‚‹
        FastForwardButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    if(m_MediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true){
                        m_MediaPlayer.pause();
                        m_Playing = true;
                    }
                    setControlPlayerTimer(m_MediaPlayer.getDuration() / Config.PLAYER_FORWARD_BACK_TIMESPAN);
                    return true;
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    if(m_Playing == true){
                        m_MediaPlayer.start();
                        m_Playing = false;
                    }
                    m_ButtonClickHandleTimer = ReleaseTimer(m_ButtonClickHandleTimer);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        settingCountTimer();

    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private Timer ReleaseTimer(Timer timer){
        if(timer != null){
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //ã‚¤ã‚³ãƒ©ã‚¤ã‚¶ãƒ¼(Equalizer):éŸ³å£°ä¿¡å�·ã�®å‘¨æ³¢æ•°ç‰¹æ€§ã‚’å¤‰æ›´ã�™ã‚‹ã‚‚ã�®
    private void setUpEqualizer(){
        m_Equalizer = new Equalizer(0, m_MediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
        //ã�“ã‚Œã�Šã�¾ã�˜ã�ªã�„ã€�ä¸€å›žç„¡åŠ¹ã�«ã�—ã�ªã�„ã�¨ã€�æœ‰åŠ¹ã�«ã�ªã�£ã�¦ã��ã‚Œã�ªã�„ã�®ã�§
        m_Equalizer.setEnabled(false);

        TextView eqTextView = new TextView(this);
        eqTextView.setText("Equalizer:");

        short bands = m_Equalizer.getNumberOfBands();

    }






    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /*
    private OnClickListener m_MediaPlayerClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(m_MediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true){
                m_MediaPlayer.pause();
                m_MediaPlayerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audioplay_icon);
            }else{
                m_MediaPlayer.start();
                m_MediaPlayerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audiopause_icon);
            }
        }
    };
    */

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /*
    private OnSeekBarChangeListener m_SeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            seekBar.setProgress(progress);
            m_MediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            m_NowTimeText.setText(Tools.ConversionTime(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            m_Playing = m_MediaPlayer.isPlaying();
            if(m_Playing == true){
                m_MediaPlayer.pause();
                //m_MediaPlayerButton.setText(R.string.AudioPlayerStartButtonText);
                m_MediaPlayerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audioplay_icon);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if(m_Playing == true){
                m_MediaPlayer.start();
                m_Playing = false;
                m_MediaPlayerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audiopause_icon);
                //m_MediaPlayerButton.setText(R.string.AudioPlayerPauseButtonText);
            }
        }
    };
    */

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //ãƒœã‚¿ãƒ³ã‚’æŠ¼ã�—ã�¤ã�¤ã�‘ã�Ÿå ´å�ˆã�®å‡¦ç�†
    private void setControlPlayerTimer(final int nMoveTime){
        if(m_ButtonClickHandleTimer == null){
            m_ButtonClickHandleTimer = new Timer(true);
        }
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int nSetPosition = m_MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() + nMoveTime;
                if(nSetPosition > m_MediaPlayer.getDuration()){
                    nSetPosition = m_MediaPlayer.getDuration();
                }else if(nSetPosition < 0){
                    nSetPosition = 0;
                }
                m_MediaPlayer.seekTo(nSetPosition);
                m_SeekBar.setProgress(nSetPosition);
                final String text = Tools.ConversionTime(nSetPosition);
                m_Handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        m_NowTimeText.setText(text);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        m_ButtonClickHandleTimer.schedule(task, 0, Config.PRESS_BUTTON_HANDLE_TIMESPAN);

    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private void settingCountTimer(){
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                m_Handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(m_MediaPlayer != null){
                            if(m_MediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true){
                                m_NowTimeText.setText(Tools.ConversionTime(m_MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                                m_SeekBar.setProgress(m_MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        m_TimeCountTimer.schedule(task, 0, 1);
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /*
    private OnCompletionListener m_AudioLitener = new OnCompletionListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            finish();
        }
    };
    */

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            finish();
        }else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
            Tools.setVolumeUp(this);
            /*
            m_nRecordVolume++;
            int nMaxVolume = m_AudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            if(nMaxVolume < m_nRecordVolume){
                m_nRecordVolume = nMaxVolume;
            }
            if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.VolumeAutoSetKey), false) == true){
                Tools.setVolume(this, m_AudioManager, m_nRecordVolume);
            }else{
                m_AudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, m_nRecordVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            }
            */
            //true:ä»–ã�®KeyEventã‚’å�–å¾—ã�§ã��ã�ªã�„ã‚ˆã�†ã�«ã�™ã‚‹
            return true;
        }else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
            Tools.setVolumeDown(this);
            /*
            m_nRecordVolume--;
            if(0 >= m_nRecordVolume){
                m_nRecordVolume = 0;
                Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                //500ãƒŸãƒªç§’ãƒ�ã‚¤ãƒ–ãƒ¬ãƒ¼ã‚·ãƒ§ãƒ³èµ·å‹•ã€‚
                vibrator.vibrate(Config.VIBRATING_TIME);
            }
            if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.VolumeAutoSetKey), false) == true){
                Tools.setVolume(this, m_AudioManager, m_nRecordVolume);
            }else{
                m_AudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, m_nRecordVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            }
            */
            //true:ä»–ã�®KeyEventã‚’å�–å¾—ã�§ã��ã�ªã�„ã‚ˆã�†ã�«ã�™ã‚‹
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Tools.setRecoedVolume(this);
        /*
        if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.VolumeAutoSetKey), false) == true){
            Tools.setVolume(this,m_AudioManager,m_nRecordVolume);
        }
        */
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //ãƒ�ãƒƒã‚¯ã‚°ãƒ©ã‚¦ãƒ³ãƒ‰å†�ç”Ÿã�¯ã�•ã�›ã�ªã�„
        if(m_MediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true){
            m_MediaPlayer.pause();
            m_MediaPlayerButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.audioplay_icon);
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        /*
        if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.VolumeAutoSetKey), false) == true){
            m_AudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, m_nOtherVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        }
        */
        Tools.setBeforeVolume(this);
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (m_Visualizer != null) {
            m_Visualizer.setEnabled(false);
            m_Visualizer.release();
            m_Visualizer = null;
        }
        if(m_MediaPlayer != null){
            m_ButtonClickHandleTimer = ReleaseTimer(m_ButtonClickHandleTimer);
            m_TimeCountTimer = ReleaseTimer(m_TimeCountTimer);
            if(m_MediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true){
                m_MediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            m_MediaPlayer.release();
            m_MediaPlayer = null;
        }
        Tools.releaseImageView(m_MediaPlayerButton);
        Tools.releaseImageView((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.BackToStartButton));
        Tools.releaseImageView((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.PlayerBackButton));
        Tools.releaseImageView((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.FastForwardButton));
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void saveVal(String progres2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MeidaPlayerActivity.this);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
          editor.putString("k", progres2);
          editor.commit();
          Log.d(TAG, "time saved : "+progres2);
          System.out.println("aaaaa "+progres2);



//  MySession mySession = new MySession();
//  mySession.MySession(MeidaPlayerActivity.this);
//  mySession.saveVal(progres2);


    }

    private String getVal(String key) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      String name = preferences.getString(key,"");

      return name;

    }
}
```

Any help would be extremely grateful I'm a new Android user as well as a beginner programmer so please do not judge

Thanks Way in  advance

Rapsong11

Comment: You should use commas and periods in your explanation; it is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Save the time from the system clock when you start recording.

```
    long beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

2 - Save the difference between the system time and new time for each button click.

```
    // set up a SparseArray to store the click times
    SparseArray<long> savedTimes = new SpareArray<long>
    ...
    // set up a counter to keep track of your clicks
    int clickNumber = 0;
    ...

    // in your buttons onClick, add the new click time
    long timeSinceRecordStart = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;        
    savedTimes.put(clickNumber, timeSinceRecordStart)
    clickNumber++;
    ...
```

3 - When you want to play back use the MediaPlayer.seekTo(int msec) method and pass it the relevant offset from your savedTimes.

Comment: I see in your code you're already using 'MediaPlayer.seekTo()'. So what bit can't you do?

Comment: By the way, things like all that unused, commented-out code make it a pain to read and follow. Also, as qwertyuiop5040 noted, use punctuation in your question to make it easier for us to read and understand what you're asking. You'll find a lot more people will then take the time to try and help you with your problem.